# Open set V in $\Re$ s.t. $f(V)$ is not open, $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to find an open set in $\Re$ s.t. $f(V)$ is not open. 
$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

It seems to me that this is a continuous function so I cannot really think of an interval where a discontinuity exists which would make it not open. Thank you

Comment: For every open $V$, $f(V)$ need not be open even if $f$ is continuous. Perhaps you are thinking of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Look at the graph. You should be able to locate an interval on the horizontal axis whose image on the vertical axis is not an open interval.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I know that but that was my starting point in search of an not open set

Comment: $V=\mathbb R$ will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V = (-1, 1).$ Then $f(V) = (e^{-1}, 1]$ which is not open